# Anchor element always coming blue, How to change it to red in aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net

Anchor element always coming blue, How to change it to red in aspx page.

I am trying this :

```
<ul style="color:Red"> 
            <li style="COLOR:red" text-decoration: underline;> <a href="jobs.aspx"> Internal Job Openings </a> </li> 
</ul>
```

But NO LUCK, it is always showing BLUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style needs to be on the anchor tag not the li tag.

```
<ul style="color:red"> 
        <li style="text-decoration: underline;"> <a style="color:red;" href="jobs.aspx"> Internal Job Openings </a> </li> 
</ul>
```

Also you should not have "color" in all caps. Everything in styles should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

try to style the anchor states:

a:link - a normal, unvisited link

a:visited - a link the user has visited

a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it

a:active - a link the moment it is clicked

for example:

```
a:link {
    color: red;
}
```